# lag multiple variables grouped by columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe with 6 columns

[image]

I need lags 1,2 for var1,var2,var3 and mydesired output should look like the one in the image.

[image]

I managed to write the code for lag 1 and its working fine as below. How should i iterate it for a list of multiple lags:

code:

```
g_df = df_m.groupby(["grp"])

def lag_by_grp(key,value_df):
    df = value_df.assign(group = key)
    return (df.set_index(['grp','abc2','abc3']).shift(1)

dfl = [lag_by_grp(g, g_df.get_group(g)) for g in g_df.groups.keys()]
d_lag = pd.concat(dfl, axis=0).reset_index()
```

Comment: what code have you tried so far?

Comment: g_df = df_m.groupby(["grp"])

def lag_by_grp(key,value_df): df = value_df.assign(group = key) return (df.set_index(['grp','abc2','abc3']).shift(1)

dfl = [lag_by_grp(g, g_df.get_group(g)) for g in g_df.groups.keys()] d_lag = pd.concat(dfl, axis=0).reset_index()

Comment: @sparkstars can you please post the data as text, rather than an image?

Comment: grp  abc2  abc3  var1  var2  var3
a     l     x     20    10    50
a     m     y     30    50    80
a     n     z     20    10    70 
b     p     a     40    30    20 
b     q     b     50    10    30
b     r     c     90    20    40


desired result:
grp   abc2   abc3   var1   var2   var3   var1_lag1   var2_lag1   var3_lag1   var1_lag2   var2_lag2   var3_lag2
a l x 20 10 50 NA NA NA NA NA NA
a m y 30 50 80 20 10 50 NA NA NA
a n z 20 10 70 30 50 80 20 10 50
b p a 40 30 20 NA NA NA NA NA NA
b q b 50 10 30 40 30 20 NA NA NA
b r c 90 90 40 50 10 30 40 30 20

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check with `shift` then `concat`

```
lag=[1,2]
df=pd.concat([df]+[df.groupby('grp')['var1','var2','var3'].shift(x).add_prefix('lag'+str(x)) for x in lag],axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks.

I am trying to calculate for each variable and this is working fine. But i am not able to perform the calculation using groupby for variable "grp"

Code:

yoy = [12]
columns_yoy = df.loc[:, 'var1':'var3']

for col in columns_y.columns:
    for x in yoy:
        columns_y.loc[:,col+"_yoy"] = (columns_y[col]/(columns_y[col].shift(x)))-1


Is there a way how I can apply groupby grp to this code or your solution that you provided